# How to use Ubuntu for load sharing with multiple NICs

Tags: networking, server, network-bridge

This situation is currently theoretical (but may become very real very soon if there is a *good* solution).

I have a server running Ubuntu Server that has 5 NICs (1 onboard, 4 expansion cards).  I have 4 internet connections from 4 different ISPs with 4 different IPs with 4 different modems (you get the idea - everything's different).  The expansion cards are connected to the modems, and the onboard NIC is connected to the upstream port on the main distribution switch in the server room, from which all the other machines will get IPs and internet access.

My goal is to equally share the load between all available connections (e.g. if #2 is out, share load on 1,3, and 4), and serve out internet to the main switch, which in turn will serve out to the other machines as well as hosting DHCP.

Latency is a big thing too.  The server must have no more than 2msec of latency from WANs in to LAN out.  This is for VoIP.

Is there a built-in way to do this, or must 3rd party software be installed.  Keep in mind, there is no GUI, and the only way into it is SSH after it is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package ifenslave-2.6 to do this. You can install this package by typing in the command `sudo apt-get install ifenslave-2.6`. There is some configuration to do but, there is a good amount of online resources out there to help you with that.

If you cannot find any good online resources for your needs I might have some resources to help you out.

I really hope this helps you out and please ask for help, I I am always here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see about doing this once everything is in place!